# Stateful Webservice vs. (Stateful Bean + Stateless WS)

Tags: web-services, ejb, jboss7.x

I have a system module in my design which must maintain its state. On the other hand I need to provide a public access to it through a web-service.

What is better to do in such a situation. Create a stateful bean which can be controlled by a stateless web-service or create a statefull web-service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to maintain core functionality(state) within your module & let others access it, but can't alter it. Also in case of changes, it will be limited to your module only, others will remain unaffected.

Performance wise also, I think it will be better to use statefull beans as web-services are called remotely & may loose the state in case of network failure etc.

They are mainly developed to interact with homogeneous/heterogenous applications and to decouple the functionality, mainly to consume/expose a service which further processes the business logic.

Also, if you are adding new external modules in future, they don't have to reimplement the functionality for maintaining state & can just reuse it.